# How to show that $f(x,y)$ are real analytical

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, analyticity

Given a real function $f(x,y)$ on $R^2$, we know that (from wiki) it is called real analytic if it is locally given by a convergent power series.

My question is that whether there has some principle to show that $f(x,y)$ is real analytic or not. A heuristic example are also helpful.